# Custom camera aspect ratio

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a custom camera view with `AVFoundation` with following code:

```
    captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice, error: &err))
    captureSession.addOutput(stillOutput)
    if err != nil {
        println("error: \(err?.localizedDescription)")
    }

    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    previewLayer?.videoGravity=AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
```

And it works well. Then I am capturing and showing image on the screen with following code:

```
    self.stillOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection){
                            (imageSampleBuffer : CMSampleBuffer!, _) in

let imageDataJpeg = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageSampleBuffer)
var pickedImage: UIImage = UIImage(data: imageDataJpeg)!
var previewImageView=UIImageView()
self.previewImageView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height:UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height)
self.previewImageView.layer.zPosition = -1
self.view.addSubview(self.previewImageView)
```

But camera works properly when i want to show preview image it looks like this:

**Camera:**

[image]

**After the shot preview:**

[image]

It should look like the camera view. How can I fix it?

Comment: what effect do you want to achieve? Blur or different button title?

Comment: No, you can see aspect ratio is not true on second image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make aspect ratio `3:4` you should set:

`captureSession.sessionPreset = .photo`